# How to get all files paths and names from removable sd-card path?

Tags: android, file, filepath

Trying to get all the file paths and names from removable sdcard  so far i am getting the path of sdcard like "/storage/BBF8-A8D3".
now on behalf of this path i want to go deeper and look for files and if there are sub directories go to them and find the files inside these sub directories.

This is giving me the path of sdcard

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static List<String> getSdCardPaths(final Context context, final boolean includePrimaryExternalStorage) {
    final File[] externalCacheDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(context);
    if (externalCacheDirs == null || externalCacheDirs.length == 0)
        return null;
    if (externalCacheDirs.length == 1) {
        if (externalCacheDirs[0] == null)
            return null;
        final String storageState = EnvironmentCompat.getStorageState(externalCacheDirs[0]);
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(storageState))
            return null;
        if (!includePrimaryExternalStorage && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated())
            return null;
    }
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (includePrimaryExternalStorage || externalCacheDirs.length == 1)
        result.add(getRootOfInnerSdCardFolder(externalCacheDirs[0]));
    for (int i = 1; i < externalCacheDirs.length; ++i) {
        final File file = externalCacheDirs[i];
        if (file == null)
            continue;
        final String storageState = EnvironmentCompat.getStorageState(file);
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(storageState))
            result.add(getRootOfInnerSdCardFolder(externalCacheDirs[i]));
    }
    if (result.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return result;
}

/**
 * Given any file/folder inside an sd card, this will return the path of the sd card
 */
private static String getRootOfInnerSdCardFolder(File file) {
    if (file == null)
        return null;
    final long totalSpace = file.getTotalSpace();
    while (true) {
        final File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
        if (parentFile == null || parentFile.getTotalSpace() != totalSpace)
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        file = parentFile;
    }
}
```

Then for finding files recursively but getting stuck

```
 public void recursiveFunction(File dirPath) {

    File f = new File(String.valueOf(dirPath));
     filesarray = f.listFiles();

     try {
         for (int i = 0; i < filesarray.length; i++) {
             if (filesarray[i].isFile()) {
                 int mid = filesarray[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".");
                 //    String ext=filesarray[i].getName().substring(mid+1,filesarray[i].getName().length());
                 FilesNamez.add(filesarray[i].getName());
                 FilesPathz.add(filesarray[i].getAbsolutePath());

             } else
                 recursiveFunction(filesarray[i].getAbsoluteFile());
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Which statement fails?  What should results look like? Also, what programming platform and language is being used?

Comment: any better solution to do this.